# Rails: get validation ranges programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, range

I've set validation in model:

```
validates_inclusion_of :height, :in => 36..96, :allow_nil => true, :message => 'must be between 3 and 8 feet'
```

Now I want to set the same validation ranges in JQ validation. I could repeat the same values in JavaScript file, but better way to do this would be getting validation range programmatically and output it through view.

How to get validation range programmatically in Rails, if possible at all?

Comment: If it is specifically for running rails validations in JS, there is a well-maintained library that does this: https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access a model's validations like so:

```
Model.validators
```

To get those particular values, something like:

```
Model.validators_on(:height).select {|v| v.class == ActiveModel::Validations::InclusionValidator}.first.options[:in]
```

Will return your range:

```
36..96
```

You can use `Range#min` and [`Range#max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-max) to get the integer values.

To make it all convenient, make a couple methods like so:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :height, :in => 36..96, :allow_nil => true, :message => 'must be between 3 and 8 feet'

  def self.min_height
    validators_on(:height).select {|v| v.class == ActiveModel::Validations::InclusionValidator}.first.options[:in].min
  end
end
```